# Permission denied apache even after chmod

Tags: permissions, apache2, chmod

I am trying to setup my LAMP server on ubuntu when i am about to change mod `chmod` of the files in the `/var/www` directory but when i try :

```
sudo chmod 0644 www/* -R
```

and

```
sudo chmod 0644 www -R
```

When i change the directory into the cd `cd www` i got permission denied and in the browser local host i get `403 Forbiddeen`  .

This is the output of ls -l in var folder

```
drw-r--r--  3 root root     4096 Jan  4 11:23 www
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo chmod -R 0644 /var/www
```

(if your apache configuration is like that)
Note: The last time I did this is about 1 year ago and I may have changed but I´m pretty sure that the options must be written before the mode.